# Why doesn't this add user id in the MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, discord.js

I am trying to insert user id into a database with discord.js when a user joins the server.

Here's the code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    connection.query("INSERT INTO userLevel (userID, userXP) VALUES ('${member.id}', 0 )", err => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("New member added successfully!");
    });
});
```

Instead of inserting user id to the userLevel table it inserts ${member.id} in the userID column.
Also, how do I delete the userinfo from the table when the user leaves the server?

Comment: use ` instead of ". see http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Munging query strings with literal values just introduces hard-to-debug syntax errors.  Learn to write the code correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    connection.query(`INSERT INTO userLevel (userID, userXP) VALUES (${member.id}, 0 )`, err => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("New member added successfully!");
    });
});
```

Change your expression from

```
"INSERT INTO userLevel (userID, userXP) VALUES ('${member.id}', 0 )"
```

to

```
`INSERT INTO userLevel (userID, userXP) VALUES (${member.id}, 0 )`
```